# Manually invoke lambda with s3 event in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Have a lambda which implements
`RequestHandler<S3Event, Void>`
and has handler as such `Void handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {log.info(" Event => " + event)....}`

`S3Event` here is of type `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;`

Trying to manually invoke the lambda without uploading any data to s3. So using `LambdaInvokerFactory` to create lambda client and lambda interface as:

```
public interface Lambdas {

        @LambdaFunction(functionName = "Foo)
        Void bar(S3Event event);
    }
```

Manually created `S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord ( of type com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3EventNotification)`  with [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) reference. Logging locally the `S3Event` after creation prints as such :

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "records": [
                {
                    "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
                    "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
                    "eventSource": "aws:s3",
                    "eventTime": {
                        "era": 1,
                        "dayOfYear": 71,
                        "year": 2021,
                        "dayOfMonth": 12,
                        "dayOfWeek": 5,
                        "weekyear": 2021,
                        "weekOfWeekyear": 10,
                        "monthOfYear": 3,
                        "millisOfDay": 0,
                        "yearOfCentury": 21,
                        "centuryOfEra": 20,
                        "millisOfSecond": 0,
                        "yearOfEra": 2021,
                        "secondOfMinute": 0,
                        "secondOfDay": 0,
                        "minuteOfHour": 0,
                        "minuteOfDay": 0,
                        "hourOfDay": 0,
                        "millis": 1615536000000,
                        "zone": {
                            "fixed": false,
                            "uncachedZone": {
                                "fixed": false,
                                "cachable": true,
                                "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
                            },
                            "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
                        },
                        "chronology": {
                            "zone": {
                                "fixed": false,
                                "uncachedZone": {
                                    "fixed": false,
                                    "cachable": true,
                                    "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
                                },
                                "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
                            }
                        },
                        "afterNow": false,
                        "beforeNow": true,
                        "equalNow": false
                    },
                    "eventVersion": "2.0",
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
                    },
                    "responseElements": {
                        "xAmzId2": "Foo",
                        "xAmzRequestId": "Bar"
                    },
                    "s3": {
                        "configurationId": "Foo",
                        "bucket": {
                            "name": "Foo",
                            "ownerIdentity": {
                                "principalId": "arn:aws:iam::Foo"
                            },
                            "arn": "arn:aws:s3::Foo"
                        },
                        "object": {
                            "key": "FooBar.txt",
                            "size": 10,
                            "eTag": "Foo",
                            "versionId": "Foo",
                            "sequencer": "Foo",
                            "urlDecodedKey": "FooBar.txt",
                            "sizeAsLong": 10
                        },
                        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
                    },
                    "userIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "arn:aws:iam::Foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But upon invoking bar(S3Event), it invokes the lambda but logs show it as empty:

```
Event => {[]}
```

### Things I tried

- Change the interface's input to `Void bar(Map<String, Object> event)`
  and invoked lambda as such `bar(ImmutableMap.of("Records", event.getRecords())`
  It invokes the lambda but following err:

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: lambdainternal.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "{"year":2021,"dayOfYear":71,"equ..."
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(Unknown Source)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord.<init>(S3EventNotification.java:386)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord.<init>(S3EventNotification.java:355)
    ... 4 more
```

This is how records are been created :

```
return new S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord(
            region,
            EVENT_NAME,
            EVENT_SOURCE,
            DateTime.now().toString(),
            EVENT_VERSION,
            new S3EventNotification.RequestParametersEntity(SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS),
            new S3EventNotification.ResponseElementsEntity(
                RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(SIZE),
                RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(SIZE)
            ),
            s3Entity,
            getUserIdentityEntity(accountId)
```

Not sure what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Does it work when you upload content?

Comment: yes, it works when I upload anything to s3 bucket, it triggers the lambda and does required actions.

Comment: I don't beleive, we need two arrays , we just need one `Records` , try by getting rid of `"records"` array layer!

Answer (score 1):

When unit testing Lambda functions in Java I recommend to use the [aws-lambda-java-tests module](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-tests) for JUnit.

Lambda has specific serialization logic which it implements which your own test code might not.

By using this testing library you will use the same serialisation logic as Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Format of S3 event source to lambda is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

It is an object with array of Records

So, it should be below, we don't need a second layer of `records` array.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Fixed that to have `records": [{...]}`, however , the `eventTime` field is not created as String , it becomes 
`"eventTime": { "year": 2019,"dayOfMonth": 3, ... }`

so it fails with `Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunctionException: Invalid format: "{"year":2019,"dayOfYear":246,"eq..."`

Comment: you are getting error when you try  `"eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z"` ?

Comment: Can't create `eventTime` with String value.  When using `new S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord( ...)` it generates `eventTime` as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here,

1. As [Balu Vyamajala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10186808/balu-vyamajala) mentioned to match the records format.
2. Was using [3.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/3.5.0) as dependency which created `eventTime` field as an object instead of string which threw `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunctionException: Invalid format: "{"year":2019,"dayOfYear":246,"eq...` upon invoking lambda. Using [2.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/2.2.8)
   created `eventTime:2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z` which solved the issue.

the current interface.

```
@LambdaFunction(functionName = Foo)
        Void Bar(S3Event payload);
```

However, `S3EventNotificationRecord` constructor is deprecated. You can create `json` doc in such [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) and use `S3EventNotification.parseJson` to get the records.